# how can I build a snap for JAVA maven?

Tags: java, snap, maven-3

I have a [maven application](https://github.com/Ghost150/Kaa_data_analytics) where I need to make a snap for it

I knew that I need to add this piece in the snapcraft.yaml

```
parts:
    webapp:
        plugin: maven
        source: [add the source code directory]
```

but I did not knew what I need to add in the

```
apps:
  client:
    command: ??
```

will you help me solve it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The command section is documented at https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/metadata and essentially needs an entry for each executable your application contains.

Comment: I have built the snap without the apps part. the prime folder does not have a bin folder. it contains  (etc, jar, lib, meta, snap, usr and var) as well as the "command-client.wrapper". 
do I miss something?